# Fourier Transforms and changing measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fourier-transform

I am working in $L^2$ and I want to change from some measure, $\rho$, to the usual measure. This measure is continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, and so, I can write it as $\rho(dt) = \rho(t)dt$. I am trying to prove the following thing:

$W_{\rho} = W_{dt}\sqrt{\rho}$, where W is some function in L².

Indeed, I have computed $\langle W,W \rangle_{\rho} = \int W² (\rho dt) = \int (W\cdot 
\sqrt{\rho})^2 dt = \langle W\cdot \sqrt{\rho}, W\cdot \sqrt{\rho} \rangle_{dt}$, and I somehow need to get the following equality:

$$ \mathcal{F}(W_{\rho}) = \mathcal{F}(W_{dt}\sqrt{\rho}) $$

where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier Transform.
But I am confused, because I am getting:

$$ \mathcal{F}(W_{\rho}) = \int e^{-2\pi i x \cdot t} W(t) \rho(t) dt = \mathcal{F}(W_{dt}\cdot \rho) $$

Where am I going wrong?